# tippy tooltip position with browser zoom in/out

Tags: javascript, angular, tippyjs

I have made a popover with [tippyjs](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/). Tippy takes next options:

```
const tippyInstance: any = tippy(element, {
            content: loaderTemplate,
            placement: 'right',
            animation: 'fade',
            animateFill: false,
            theme: 'kpi-tooltip',
            trigger: 'manual',
            interactive: true,
            onHidden: () => {
                tippyInstance.destroy();
            },
            allowHTML: true
        });
```

"Element" is a plain html element and content loading after response from server. The problem is when i make browser zoom in or zoom out the tooltips changes position. I'm using chrome last version.

Tooltip in normal state:[image]
Tooltip with zoom in: [image]

Answer (score 1):

"appendTo" property option solved the problem.